# Which JQuery document.ready is better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery $( function() {} ) and $(document).ready the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595913/jquery-function-and-document-ready-the-same)

Do you know which one is better and why?

The first one;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code
});
```

The second One :

```
$(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter. I'm more of a fan of the 2nd case because its easier to type.

This is what the function does internally.

```
// HANDLE: $(function)
// Shortcut for document ready
} else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
   return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Less verbose, but is well-known to most jQuery devs.

Comment: @Daniel yeah, I asked that because I wanna use the second one after that if the performance is the same or better.

Comment: the performance would be about the same. i wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @Daniel cool then. Second one wins.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not gonna wait for other answers. An answer from **31.8k-reputation-point-guy** must be correct after all.

Comment: @Daniel ok can't accept it as an answer. should wait for 9 minutes according to this annoying orange box.

Comment: I also like the 2nd since its the easiest for me to construct by hand ... just start with $() and fill in your handler.

Comment: does this work as well? : `(function () { /*Code here*/ })($)`

Comment: @Daniel hmm, I tried it and it worked but not in a correct way?       **(function () {alert("hello");})($)**

Comment: it is not equvilant. its basically saying `function myFunc() { ... }; myFunc($);`

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent.  It depends on how verbose or concise you want to be.

Answer (score 1):

All three of the following syntaxes
 are equivalent:

```
 $(document).ready(handler)
 $().ready(handler) // (this is not recommended)
 $(handler)
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same
reference : http://api.jquery.com/ready/