# What's the difference between $(document).ready(…) and $(function() {}) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

What's the difference between:

```
$(document).ready(function() {// Do something});
```

and

```
$(function() {//Do something});
```

in jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
$(handler)
```

are equivalent.

Actually, you can call `.ready(handler)` on *any* jQuery object, no matter what it contains, and it will do the same thing:

```
ready: function( fn ) {
    // Attach the listeners
    jQuery.bindReady();

    // Add the callback
    readyList.add( fn );

    return this;
},
```

Answer (score 4):

If I try in short then, they are **alias**. They are equivalent.

#### NOTE

```
$(document).ready(function() {

})


$().ready(function() {
  // this is not recommended
}) 

$(function() {

});
```

All are same.

---

#### More

jQuery developers recommend using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

Why `$().ready()` not recommend see [Why "$().ready(handler)" is not recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753306/why-readyhandler-is-not-recommended)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't.

From the jQ API:

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> ```
>  $(document).ready(handler)
>  $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
>  $(handler)
> ```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

They are the same(means they do the same thing). Check these lines from doc

```
All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
$(handler)
```

And actually `$(handler)` is an hardcoded shortcut to `$(document).ready(handler)`. In the source code here http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js if you seach for `rootjQuery` you will soon find these line

```
// HANDLE: $(function)
        // Shortcut for document ready
        } else if ( jQuery.isFunction( selector ) ) {
            return rootjQuery.ready( selector );
        }
```

Or check this link https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/37ffb29d37129293523bf1deacf3609a28b0ceec/src/core.js#L174 to find out

Means if the passed `selector` is a function, then it is used as `$(document).ready(` handler.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Also check [Which JQuery document.ready is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332760/which-jquery-document-ready-is-better)