# How can i callback from infinity scroll?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

What's the correct way to callback from infinity scroll? currently this `

```
$(function() {
    code(); 
    $('#catview').infinitescroll({ 
        dataType: 'html',
        navSelector: 'div.nextPage',
        nextSelector: 'div.nextPage a:first',
        itemSelector: '#catalogue',
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: '',
            msgText: '',
            img: '/../../../images/loading.gif',
        },
        debug: true,
        animate: true 

    }, $(function() {
        code();
    }));
    });`
```

Doens't work :( if i set an alert before code() i will see it when page loads and that's it... the other part of the code is :

```
    function code() {
alert('1')
    $('.teest').caroufredsel({
        direction: 'left',
        circular: true, 
        items: {
            visible: 1, 
            minimum: 2, 
        },
        scroll: {
            fx: 'fade', 
            easing: 'easeOutCubic', 
            duration: 200, 
        },
        auto: {
            duration: 1600
        },
        width: 208,
        height: 265,
        prev: {
            button: '.prev'
        },
        next: {
            button: '.next'
        } 
    });
}
```

all i see if run those 2 codes is the alert 1 , the caroufredsel working on the first page, if i scroll down to seconds page nothing happens, it just loads

Comment: Any chance you can set up a jsfiddle? Or give a link to the page in question?

Comment: Yes a link.. : http://dokimastiko.14u-fashion.com/shop/cat/65
1/3/2/1 should pop up that's here : $(function() {
  alert('2'); /
  code();  
 }));
 alert('3');

Comment: If the alert inside code() is happening, the callback is working. If the rest of the expected behavior isn't happening, it's likely a problem with the rest of the stuff inside code(). My guess is that something is up with your caroufedsel code.

Comment: yes but the alert happens BEFORE the infinity scroll gets activated , i noticed this TypeError: J.call is not a function on console, hmm...

Comment: It looks like there's a javascript error whenever new content is loaded. I can't really tell what the problem is because you're using the minified version of the infinitescroll script. If you used the unminified version, it'd be easier to debug.

Comment: indeed using the "full" version helps, didn't think about it..
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'call' jscroll.js:175
opts.callback jscroll.js:175
infscr_loadcallback jscroll.js:389
infscr_ajax_callback jscroll.js:561
e.extend.each jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
e.fn.e.each jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
f.ajax.complete jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
o jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
p.fireWith jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2
w jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
d jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4
(where jscroll is the infinity-scroll plugin)

Comment: See my answer. It may help you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :-

```
$(function() {

    $('#catview').infinitescroll({
        dataType: 'html',
        navSelector: 'div.nextPage',
        nextSelector: 'div.nextPage a:first',
        itemSelector: '#catalogue',
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: '',
            msgText: '',
            img: '/../../../images/loading.gif',
        },
        debug: true,
        animate: true 
    },
    function(arrayOfNewElems)
    {
         code();
    });
});
```

As per `Infinite Scroll Jquery` [documentation](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/comment-page-1/) call back function change your code

```
 $(function() {
    code();
 }));
```

to

```
function(arrayOfNewElems){
 //here your collaback function
});
```

Comment: i think i have to enclose the function inside a $(document).ready(function() {

});

Comment: both `$(function() {` and `$(document).ready(function() {` are same. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894777/whats-the-difference-between-document-ready-and-function-in-jquer

Comment: yes nothing works is see this TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'call'

Answer (score 0):

Turns out $(function... is readed as **object** from the javascript engine , and infinity-scroll cannot callback objects. Removing all the $ from the function solve everything